# How do I add a class to an element and keep it there until the mouse leaves with animate.css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animate.css

I have an element in which an animation is applied to it via animate.css when the page loads...

```
<div class="logo></div>
```

...the bounce class is added, and when the animation is done, the bounce class is removed:

```
$(".logo").addClass("bounce");
$('.logo').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("bounce");
});
```

Once the above has been executed, I would like the animation to now occur when the ".logo" is hovered:

```
$(".logo").hover(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("bounce");
});
```

However, after the logo is hovered, the ".bounce" class is removed and the animation only occurs when the mouse leaves the logo due to this code:

```
$('.logo').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("bounce");
});
```

How can I write the code so that the animation occurs when the page not only loads, but also only when the logo is hovered and not when the mouse leaves?

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://github.com/craigmdennis/animateCSS

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to only add the new event after the animation is completed the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the first attached events with `.off(...)` and then add a new hover event:

```
$(".logo").addClass("bounce");

$('.logo').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){

  $(this).removeClass("bounce");

  $('.logo').off('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend');

  $( ".logo" ).hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "bounce" );
    }, function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "bounce" );
    }
  );

});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, @signal2013! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This one got me thinking, so here's a free one even though there's already an accepted answer.  I started wondering if there was a way to do this without the JavaScript, since `:hover` is obviously available in CSS.

Looking at the animate.css source, the class they made available if you want the animation to be continuous is `.infinite` and there's only one rule associated with it: `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

That means you could simply add that property to your `:hover` selector and you're off and running - no JS required.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaBKdq

HTML:

```
<!-- Animation will run once on page load by adding classes 'bounce' 
     and 'animated' directly in the markup -->
<div class="logo animated bounce></div>
```

CSS:

```
/** Make Animation continuous when hovered**/
.logo:hover {
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

As a bonus, if you're including animate.css in an SCSS compilation, you can also just use the `@extend` syntax, which is pretty slick in this case:

```
.logo:hover {
  @extend .infinite; 
}
```